# Error Specified cast is not valid

Tags: c#

I have the below function

```
SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(constring);
cn.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select max(ID) from EP_PATTERNS ", cn);
int h = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar() + 1;
txtID.Text = h.ToString();
cn.Close();
```

How to fix this Error:

> Specified cast is not valid.

Comment: You have to specifiy where the exception occurs.

Comment: int h = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar() + 1;

Comment: please put more details about the error, it may be in another part of the code, is it a compiler error or a runtime exception

Comment: If the table is empty, the return value will be `DBNull.Value`. And this will leads to this exception. You have to check this before fallbacking to 0.

Comment: int h = (int) (decimal) cmd.ExecuteScalar() + 1;

Comment: It's good to test your SQL Code in an SQL IDE first when debugging this kind of error.

Comment: @ChibuezeOpata +1 on that one.

Comment: What is the full message? Something like "cannot convert type XXX to type `System.Int32`". Maybe @vadz solution will work.

Answer (score 3):

given your code I feel the easiest way to fix the logic is to edit the SQL to

```
select ISNULL(max(ID),0) from EP_PATTERNS
```

To better understand what this does you can run this SQL in SSMS:

```
DECLARE @table table (ID int);
SELECT MAX(ID) FROM @table;
SELECT ISNULL(MAX(ID), 0) FROM @table;
```

Answer (score 2):

Whether table `EP_PATTERNS` contains any rows? Otherwise you a trying to cast `NULL` to `int` and fails.

You code should looks like:

```
SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(constring);
cn.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select max(ID) from EP_PATTERNS ", cn);
var value = (int?)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
int maxId = value.HasValue ? value.Value + 1 : 0;  //Increase value or default it to zero
txtID.Text = maxId.ToString();
cn.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `coalesce` you can achieve this:

```
con.Open();
cmd.Connection = con;
cmd.CommandText = "select coalesce(max(user_id),0)+1 from user_master";
int user_id = int.Parse(cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
txt_user_id.Text = user_id.ToString();
con.Close();
```